# Fan on new Mobo won't slow down

Tags: windows, bios, fan

I recently replaced a motherboard with an Asrock 960GC-GS and the fans run at 4000RPM continuously.

I went into the BIOS and played with the CPU fan speed by changing to level 1 from a 9 and it still runs the same fast speed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your temperatures like?  My guess is you are using a low power cable.  How many pins does the cable have?

Comment: It's a 250W power supply. Last I saw was 35C on the CPU from within the BIOS. It's a 24PIN power connector. The last 4 was optional so maybe I plugged them in on the wrong side?

Comment: There are different types of fan cables my statement has nothing to do with your power supply.  There is no such thing as a 24-pin fan.  I am asking about the fan cable nothing else.

Comment: So I could have them plugged into the wrong places?

Comment: Unless you didn't plug in the CPU fan into the CPU Fan Header.

Comment: CPU FAN is in the CPU Fan slot. So that is not it.

Comment: This a stock or after market CPU heatsink?

Comment: It was the same one in before. So stock.